# How to remove multiple spaces from a C++ program and put one space instead it

Tags: c++

How to remove multiple spaces from a C++ program and put one space instead it?

What I tried was:-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char str[80],i, j;
    cin>>str;
    for(i=0; i!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(str[i]=' '&&str[i]==str[i+1])
        {
            for(j=i+1; str[j]!='\0'; j++)
                str[j-1]=str[j];
        }
    }
    cout<<str;
}
```

Comment: What did it do?  Destroy all the indentation?

Comment: Do you have to use C++ or can you find an editor that will handle this?  Something like notepad++ or emacs can take care of this in very little time...  I take it you are trying to use your program at the command line between pipe or STDIN STDOUT redirect arrows?

Comment: I am a school student and am being taught C++, I found this question in my book but wasn't able to run the program correctly...Also I don't know much of the things you said @abiessu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cin` truncates the string whenever it encounters a space. To read the entire line use `getline()`. Also I recommend using `std::string`.

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin,str);

for(i=str.size()-1; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        if(str[i]==' '&&str[i]==str[i-1]) //added equal sign
        {
            str.erase( str.begin() + i );
        }
    }
```

Loop iterates from the end so that
1. The `str.size()` complication is removed.
2. A bit of efficiency is introduced in the erase operation (if there are a lot of spaces).

Comment: but i have not been taught all this

Comment: @gaurav I have added the references.

Comment: This is erasing a bit too much, I think (but the question is somewhat ambiguous).

Comment: @MSalters Aah! Mis-understood the question. Thanks for pointing out. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Is it a good idea to modify the string while its length represents number of iterations?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi This is the reason why we iterate from the end of the string. Even if the string length changes, the loop counter is always in the "safe zone".

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this approach:

```
wstring str = L"Hallo  x     y   111 2222  3333 rrr 4444   ";

size_t len1 = str.length();

wstring::iterator I = unique( str.begin(), str.end(), [](auto lhs, auto rhs){ return lhs == rhs && lhs == ' '; } );
str.erase( I, str.end() );

size_t len2 = str.length();
```

You can simply use the `std::unique()` function and the `wstring::iterator` to remove all duplicates. You'll need a custom predicate because you want to get rid only of multiple blanks.

Answer (score 2):

With [`<regex>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) of C++11:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);

std::regex space_re(R"(\s+)");

std::cout << std::regex_replace(line, space_re, " ") << '\n';
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/h8D0N0)

Answer (score 1):

In C++, better use `string` type instead of C char arrays. Also, use `string` member functions, and also `getline`.

```
std::string line;
std::getline( cin, line );
size_t pos;
while( ( pos = line.find( "  " ) )!=std::string::npos )
    line = line.replace( pos, 2, " " );
```

Not efficient if there are many double spaces in the line, but easy to read and understand.

In C++11, `regex` would be the killer!

Answer (score 0):

Actually your solution is not bad but you have to fix a few issues:

- You should compare str[i+1] to `\0` not i (in the outer cycle)
- you should also copy the `\0` symbol in the inner cycle.
- You should read whole lines using `getline` instead of just `cin >> str` as `cin` will read chars until the next whitespace.

Comment: what is the header file of getline?

Comment: @gaurav `iostream`. Please also consider using `std::string`(from `string` header instead of `c`-style character array like `Abhishek Bansal` proposes

Answer (score 0):

The function `std::search` can search for multiple adjacent elements at a time. It's a *template* function, so it can search for multiple types: music notes in a score, but also characters in a string.

In your case, you of course want to search for 2 adjacent spaces, i.e.

```
char const* pattern = "  ";
auto result = std::search(begin(str), end(str), pattern, pattern+2);
```

Note that pattern also contains an `\0` end of string, but we don't pass that to search - we're not searching for two spaces before a `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer.

My idea is to to avoid iterating character by character. Basically find 2 subsequent spaces. Then character by character goes on until the character is a space. When the character is not a space anymore then the sequence of spaces is ended. Now you have the indexes to delete.

Repeat until the process until in the string two subsequent spaces are found.

```
void removeMultiSpace(string&str)
{
  //cout<<str<<endl;
  size_t _start;
  size_t _end;
  //first we'll find the position of the subsequent spaces
  while(size_t i = str.find("  "))
  {
       if (i==string::npos)
       {
         //if none is found then exit
         return;
       }
      // initialize the indexes
      _start = i;
      _end = i+1;
      //iterate char by char until there are spaces
      // and increase the _end index
      while(str.at(_start) == str.at(_end))
      {
        _end++;
      }
      //erase the white sapces leaving just one
      str.erase(_start, _end-_start-1);


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void removeMultipleSpaces(string &str){
    uint32_t i=0;
    uint32_t gotSpace=0;
    while (i<str.length())
    {
        if(str[i]==' ')
            gotSpace++;
        else
            gotSpace=0;
        
        if (gotSpace>1)
        {
            str.erase(i,1);
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Any good solution would involve using `std::string` and
`std::getline`.  But with regards to your code:

- The `>>` operator for `char*` (and for `std::string`) skips
  leading spaces, and stops at the first space.  Which means that
  if you use `cin >> str`, there will never be a space in `str`.
- You don't check that the input succeeded before using the
  value that was read.
- You'll never enter your loop, since the initial condition is
  `i == 0`, and you only loop if `i != 0`.
- Finally, you're doing an awful lot of unnecessary copying.

Assuming part of your problem is that you are in a course taught
by someone completely incompetent, who presents C style arrays
before std::vector and std::string: you still need to use
`getline`, and the simplest solution after that would be to use
two pointers, a destination and a source.  Something like:

```
std::cin.getline( str, sizeof( str ) );
if ( !cin ) {
    char* dest = str;
    char* source = str;
    while ( *source != '\0' ) {
        *dest = *source;
        ++ dest;
        if ( *source == ' ' ) {
            while ( *source == ' ' ) {
                ++ source;
            }
        } else {
            ++ source;
        }
    }
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

(If you've not yet learned pointers, you can do the same thing
with two indices.  But using pointers here would be far more
idiomatic C++.  And C, for that matter.)

Comment: "Assuming part of your problem is that you are in a course taught by someone completely incompetent, who presents C style arrays before std::vector and std::string"


This is, I am sure, endlessly debatable and heavily opinion based, but the tone is certainly needlessly harsh.